# Is there a way to know who made a change in my AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have setup event subscriptions for every action in RDS so I can be notified each time there is a change in the RDS infrastructure.

However , when the email arrives there is no info on which aws user made the change so to talk directly with him.

Is there such an option in AWS ?

Comment: Perhaps CloudTrail is what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmmm...maybe you are right. I have only read about CT, so I'll give it a go.Thanks

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer so you can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

CloudTrail should have the required features you are looking for - 
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/